Handling the positive square root of the commutator of two positive definite matrices.
Let $A,B>0$ be non-commuting positive definite operators. Define the commutator to be
$$[A,B] = AB - BA$$
For every operator $A$, $A^*A$ is always positive, and its unique positive square root is denoted $|A|$.
Can one simplify $|[A,B]|$
in terms of A and B?

Note that $[A,B]^* = (AB-BA)^* = BA-AB = -[A,B]$, so
$$ | [A,B] | = \left(- [A,B]^2\right)^{1/2}$$
i.e. the unique positive semidefinite square root of $-[A,B]^2$.
I don't think it can be "simplified" any more than that.
